# Sub entity doesn't update when assign null value to its reference

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an entity named: **Application** and it has field **ApplicationStatus** which is entity as well, ApplicationStatus values are yes or no and it's nullable in Application.

So when I execute:

```
Application application = MyEntities.Applications.First();
application.ApplicationStatus = null; 
MyEntities.SaveChanges();
```

ApplicationStatus won't update its value, **unless** I debug it and do quick watch application.ApplicationStatus.

However

```
application.ApplicationStatusId = null;
```

works fine.

My question, why this one doesn't work:

application.ApplicationStatus = null;

Thanks

**EDIT** *further question:*

As @LadislavMrnka answer solves debug behaviour and and the issue related lazy loading:

how can we interpret these situation?

```
Application application = MyEntities.Applications.First();

application.ApplicationStatusId = null; //This updates value in db

ApplicationStatus applicationStatus = MyEntities.ApplicationStatuses.First(a => a.Name == "no");
app.ApplicationStatus = applicationStatus; //This updates value in db too

app.ApplicationStatus = null; // But this doesn't
```

Comment: If you don't load the `ApplicationStatus` with `Include`, as Ladislav proposed, the `application.ApplicationStatus` is `null` (or an empty lazy loading proxy) and when you set it to `null` EF doesn't detect any change -> result: No update statement for the property. The foreign key property `ApplicationStatusId` is scalar and therefore always loaded. If you set it to `null` EF detects a change in that property -> result: Update statement to DB. I'd say: Be happy with the FK property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this and it will work:

```
Application application = MyEntities.Applications.Include("ApplicationStatus").First();
```

The reason is that your `ApplicationStatus` was never loaded. If you do debug and access it your debugging access will trigger lazy loading and loads it.